# VBA Copy Variable Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm have a template which has one work sheet as the input sheet. This is where the user enters building address information. I then run a macro that transfers this data into an input sheet. I have three columns of data that can have a variable row number sometimes one location other times 500 and over.

So I have set up a location count variable and am trying to copy the data into the other sheet but keep getting the 1004 error object defined. I'm sure its something simple but I just can't work it out.

The code I have is:

```
With WsInput
    LocCount = .Range("B18", .Range("B18").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End With

With WsLoc
    .Range("D:F").Value = WsInput.Range(.Cells(17 + LocCount, 2), .Cells(17 + LocCount, 5).Value)
End With
```

Comment: If you want one range of cells to equal another range of cells, the ranges need to be the same size.

Comment: Thanks, thats the problem as the range varies in size so its hard to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the source using cells in the target.

Stay inside the first With ... End With and use the source to set the rows and columns of the target.

```
With WsInput

    LocCount = .Range("B18", .Range("B18").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    with .Range(.Cells(17 + LocCount, 2), .Cells(17 + LocCount, 5))
        WsLoc.Range("D1").resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .Value
    end with

End With
```

That code seems to contradict itself. Perhaps you meant something like this.

```
With WsInput

    LocCount = .Range("B18", .Range("B18").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    with .Range(.Cells(18, 2), .Cells(17 + LocCount, 5))
        WsLoc.Range("D1").resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .Value
    end with

End With
```

Comment: Thanks user11217663 I have just noticed that myself. Now that the code is working I could see that my variable range was wrong. Thanks for your help, works perfectly now.